# %64[^ specificator in C

Tags: c

```
sscanf(line, "%d %64[^\n", &seconds, message);
```

does **%64[^** mean - up to 64 characters?
Should it work with GNU C Compiler?

Comment: I may be wrong.. but you miss an 's' right.. ie %64[^\n]s..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means "read at most 64 characters or stop when reaching a newline, whichever comes first". It's specified by the standard so all standard libraries have to support it.

> C11 7.21.6.2
>
> `[` Matches a nonempty sequence of characters from a set of expected
>   characters (the scanset).
>   [...]
>   The conversion specifier includes all subsequent characters in the
>   format string, up to and including the matching right bracket (]).
>
> The characters between the brackets (the scanlist) compose the
>   scanset, unless the character after the left bracket is a circumflex
>   (^), in which case the scanset **contains all characters that do not
>   appear in the scanlist** between the circumflex and the right bracket.

As noted in the comments, a matching `]` is probably required to delimit the scanlist. **An `s` specifier is not required**.

Comment: Wow, had no idea. Need to read up on that stuff. I would say, "all C libraries have to support it", though.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant Good call on the wording.

Comment: What about Krishnabhadras comment to the OP? An 's'

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant The standard doesn't say it can be omitted but I expect some implementations can do without a matching `]`.

Comment: And an 's'... not just the ending ]

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant No, `s` isn't required. In this case `[` is the `s`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11729/discussion-between-amigable-clark-kant-and-cnicutar)